# Drupal 7 views: show users friends who flagged event problem

Tags: views, flags

I am having a problem with views.

I want to display a block on the node event. The contains a list of users who flagged the event. The list of users must be friends with the logged in user.

What I have now is a list of users who flagged the current event. I have tried to show a list of only friends but it wont show anybody.

Here's a couple of screenshots of the current settings:

[image: snap1]
[image: snap2]
[image: snap3]
[image: snap4]

I hope this great community can help me with this problem!

Comment: Now your showing all the people who flagged the node, there is no filter for your friends. How do you define friends, do you have another flag? (flag friends or so) You can add another relation with your flagged friends and filter out all the non-friends. succes ermee